# After install play on Mac, under terminal, I typed 'play' but throws error

Tags: playframework

I used "brew install play" in terminal installed play successfully 
but after installation, I typed "play" to test, those errors were throwed

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/useruser/Project
[info] Set current project to useruser (in build file:/Users/useruser/)
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: apply, last, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: clean)
```

[error] play
 [error]     ^

What is wrong with my play framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you already started play. Try now "run" to launch the server

Answer (score 0):

`play` must be launch in a play project.

Just try to create a new empty project with `play new myAwesomeProject`, and relaunch `play` in the folder created.